# R - Entering a sequence of number in if loop follows only one condition

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am making a function which puts leading zeroes to number to make it a 3-digit string and adding .csv to each. This is my code

```
filename <- function(id) {
  
  if (id<10) {
    file_name=paste("00",id,".csv", sep="")
  }
  else if (id<100) {
    file_name=paste("0",id,".csv", sep="")
  }
  else  {
    file_name=paste(id,".csv", sep="")
    }
  file_name
}
```

When I entered filename(1:12), the following was the output

```
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used [1] "001.csv"  "002.csv"  "003.csv"  "004.csv"  "005.csv"  "006.csv"  "007.csv"  "008.csv"  "009.csv"  "0010.csv"
[11] "0011.csv" "0012.csv"
```

Basically my problem is that once the id comes to 10, it still follows the 1st if condition. When it comes to id=10 and higher, the supposed output should be 010.csv and so on. How can I fix my code?

Comment: `stringr::str_pad(1:12, width=4, pad="0")`.

Comment: `sprintf('%03d.csv', 1:12)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your function is not vectorized, i.e. the if-condition uses only the first element of 1:12 (= 1) to check the condition. Using `stringr::str_pad` you can achieve your desired result like so:

```
paste0(stringr::str_pad(1:12, width = 3, pad = "0"), ".csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Import strings
`library(stringr)`

define all filenames

```
filename<-seq(1:12)
```

Write a function Y which returns 3 digit name

```
Y<-function(id){
  paste(stringr::str_pad(id, width=3, pad="0"),".csv", sep="")
  
}
```

use apply to call it

```
lapply(filename,Y)
```